# Local images are failing for tasks in Openshift pipelines 1.11

Tags: openshift, tekton, openshift-pipelines

I have following task definition (simplified):

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Task
metadata:
  name: my-task
  namespace: mynamespace
  params:
    - default: 'image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/mynamespace/mytaskimage'
      description: image used to execute this task
      name: task-image
      type: string
  steps:
    - command:
        - ./runscript.sh
      image: $(params.task-image)
      name: run-script
      resources: {}
```

This task was working fine in Openshift pipelines 1.10.6 but is failing in 1.11.1

It is failing with error:

```
Generated from TaskRun
build step "step-run-script" is pending with reason "rpc error: code = Unknown desc = reading manifest latest in image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/mynamespace/mytaskimage: manifest unknown"
```

Any hints how to use local images in task in 1.11+ pipelines?
The task image is in the same namespace.

Comment: "image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/mynamespace/mytaskimage" is the name of the image? there is no tag ?, ie "image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/mynamespace/mytaskimage:<tag>" ? does the repository has this image name with the "latest" tag?

Comment: yes it is the name of the image, and yest there is latest tag in the repo. There are no other tags. Behavior is the same whether you use mytaskimage or mytaskimage:latest